# Parameter page=0 gives problem in rules

Tags: rules

I have a rule which is activated with the following url

redirect/startcoursewithpage?course=502&page=1&module=471

The condition of the rule is:
- Check if URL argument exist for course
- Check if URL argument exist for page
- Check if URL argument exist for module.

The parameter values of course and module will never be 0. The page can be of a value of zero.

If the parameter page=0 is given in the url the condition is not true and the redirect is not done. If I remove the condition Check if URL argument exist for page it is working.

The value zero is directly from the database from another view. I think I should uuencode this zero value but I do’n know how. Other suggestions?

Comment: What is your rule exactly? Is it a data comparison? Seems to be checking if page is true rather than if is set.

Comment: I just came across the [rules url argument module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument). I will assume you are using that/

Comment: Yes i'm using that module. Field page in cType is integer with a text widget. But I'm not getting in the action part of the rule yet. Already at the conditions is stopping and in the conditions is only a check if it is available, not converting...

Comment: Added an answer

Comment: I changed the function. The code is working in the conditions but as if I used it as a incoming integer in the provide url argument action it does not redirect..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Might help if you show the path that you are trying to redirect to. Also maybe comment under my answer if it did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look through the code of the module, the function that checks if the url parameter exists is this:

```
/**
 * Rules condition callback.
 *
 * Checks if the specified URL argument is set.
 */
function rules_url_argument_argument_exists($argument) {
  return !empty($_GET[$argument]);
}
```

This will return false if the argument is 0.

I think it should really be this:

```
/**
 * Rules condition callback.
 *
 * Checks if the specified URL argument is set.
 */
function rules_url_argument_argument_exists($argument) {
  return isset($_GET[$argument]);
}
```

Might be a good idea to submit an issue (and maybe a patch) in the modules [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/rules_url_argument?status=All&categories=All).
**I'm not exactly sure why the function gets the argument argument and doesn't use it**
I have never used this module BTW.

**EDIT:**
There is also `if (!empty($_GET[$argument_name])) {` on line 71 of the module file that might need changing to `isset`.

Comment: As it is such a small module, You could just recreate it and change the `!empty` to `isset` and be all good.

Comment: I have added an issue to the module issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2464703

Comment: Asjusting the code is helping a litte bit but it not solving the problem. If I replace the action with an action call "Add a variable "and using some php code, the value is somehow somewhere lost in the next action which is send a message to the screen. Also in this action "all a variable"if you want to add a integer you cannot use php code. So i looks something strange in rules but where and how is very unclear for me. I solved the problem with a work around like <?php
$a = $_REQUEST['page'];
If ($a <= 0) {
 $a = 1;
}
return $a;
?>

Comment: Seems to me like there are a few problems with the module. It might be worth adding your thoughts to the issue I posted.